# Почему изменен порядок показа ответов?

Tags: поддержка, faq, статус-так-задумано

Почему с недавнего времени на сайте действует какой-то странный порядок показа ответов?

Теперь почему-то [ответы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/544/c%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) с отрицательным рейтингом наверху, а принятый ответ — внизу (или все как-то по-другому, но не как надо). И это везде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как было написано @br3t, настроить порядок отображения ответов можно на панели под ником автора вопроса: *[скриншот](https://monosnap.com/file/PRHWjdtjRfYjPP9nWpRevG5cdsSX4P)*.

Answer (score 0):

Это настройки ваши.
У меня проблем нет.

Comment: Я бы изменил, да нигде такие настройки найти не могу. Не подскажете где?

Comment: Да вот сам потерял ))) Сейчас найду.

Comment: Слушайте, очень стыдно, но не нашел.  Если не разберетесь, вечером (поздно) посмотрю ещё. Сейчас не могу тут сидеть.

Comment: Похоже на настройки https://monosnap.com/file/PRHWjdtjRfYjPP9nWpRevG5cdsSX4P

Comment: @br3t спасибо. похоже, это то